# Group & sum hashes by month, including when no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date range that I'm using to query a database with. The returned result is an array of hashes like so:

```
[
  {:created=>"2013-12-10", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-02-20", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-02-23", :amount=>4}, 
  {:created=>"2014-02-24", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-06", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-14", :amount=>3}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-15", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-17", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-20", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-21", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-24", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-25", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-03-28", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-04-05", :amount=>1}, 
  {:created=>"2014-04-07", :amount=>1}
]
```

What I need to do is group and sum the `amount` by month, and in the case where a month has no data but is part of the initial range, show `0`.

So in my example above, the date range I queried the database with was `2013-11-13` to `2014-04-18`.

Output is ultimately just a basic array of the data grouped month and summed. So the example above should produce:

```
[0, 1, 0, 6, 11, 2]
```

Those array items coordinate to: November, December, January, February, March, April.

FWIW, I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 and this is part of a Rails 4 app, if there happen to be some special Rails helper methods that would be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#group_by` methods to group by year, and month, and then combination of `#map`, `#uniq`, and `#reduce` to get proper `Array`:

```
# grouping record by year and month, and then sorting them
g = a.group_by {|v| Date.parse(v[:created][0,7] + '-01') }.sort

# generating a result hash
h = Hash[g]

# generating range
range = Date.new(2013,11)..Date.new(2014,04)

# here we firstly remap to get *year-month* list by dates, which will contain only
# one date per month, then we calculate sum for each month value.
range.to_a.map {|d| Date.new(d.year,d.month,1)}.uniq.map {|d| h[d] && h[d].reduce(0) {|sum,h| sum + h[:amount]} || 0 }

# => [0, 1, 0, 6, 11, 2]
```

for [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) you can use `#try` method:

```
range.to_a.map {|d| Date.new(d.year,d.month,1)}.uniq.map {|d| h[d].try(:reduce, 0) {|sum,h| sum + h[:amount]} || 0 }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something...this isn't what I'm looking for at all. As mentioned, the data needs to be summed and it needs to account for missing months.

Comment: I actually just realized a use case that this won't work with. Take the initial date range. In my example I mentioned the range started on `2013-11-13`. If there's no data in the month of November, this won't work.

Comment: @Shpigford so the dates before 2013-11-13 sould not be calculated? or what?

Comment: Well they wouldn't be pulled in the query. My database query example had it pulling with a date range starting on `2013-11-13`. So say there were no records for 2013-11-13 through 2013-11-31...I still need to show a "0" in the final array for that month.

Comment: @Shpigford But you have it in the test request: `{:created=>"2013-11-16", :amount=>1},` isn;t it the proper data?

Comment: I'm saying there's an additional use case to test your solution with. Yes your current answer matches the test data, but my original request mentioned grouping and summing by month even when a month was missing/had no data. So instead of a month missing in the middle of the data, it could also be at the beginning.