# rails group by date and sum quantity mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a cross-tab of info. I can get it to group by date but I am having a hard time totaling them by unit code. I am also struggling with how to make the view display correctly. I would like to show the date in the column instead of it showing as a row. I used [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) as guidance to sum. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158176/group-sum-hashes-by-month-including-when-no-data) but its a little over my head to be honest.

Sample Data

```
|Productiondate| Unit Code | Quantity
|   2017-1-1   |   Part 1  |   2    | 
|   2017-1-1   |   Part 1  |   3    | 
|   2017-1-22  |   Part 1  |   1    |
|   2017-1-1   |   Part 2  |   3    |
|   2017-1-10  |   Part 2  |   1    |
|   2017-1-22  |   Part 2  |   1    |
```

End Result Table

```
|Unit Code | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3
-------------------------------------
|   Part 1 |   5    |   0    |  1  |
|   Part 2 |   3    |   1    |  1  |
```

reportcontroller.rb

```
def workorder_production
    #@productions = Production.all
    #@production_weeks = @productions.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_week } 
    productions = Production.select(:unitcode, :created_at, sum(:quantity).group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_week })
  end
```

The lines that are commented above will work but will not total the quantity When I try the uncomment portion I get

> NoMethodError undefined method `sum'

workorder_production.html.erb

```
<% @production_weeks.sort.each do |week, productions| %>
  <h2>Week Number <%= week.strftime('%U') %></h2>
  <% for production in productions %>
    <div class="production">
      <p>Unit Code: <%= production.unitcode %> Qty: <%= production.quantity %></p>

          </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update the question with the sample data formatted for ruby (i.e. as an array of hashes) - that way people can copy the code and attempt to fix, rather than having to input it all manually. That be possible? If so, happy to take a look :)

Comment: Try to do something like this: `Production.select('column1', 'column2', 'sum(column3)')...`. Right now you call sum method with :quantity as argument. Of course it gives the error

Comment: @SRack I am not sure how to produce a hash. Let chase that one down...